# how to use getopt to parse one option only once

Tags: c, getopt, getopt-long

i want to parse one option ONLY ONCE and **make it skip or make an error** when there are two different options that conflict each other entered in argument.

for example,

```
./a.out --install --remove //i dont want this to work...
```

i was thinking of setting var to store whether option has been read
something like:

```
case 'i': install_opt=1; install_arg=optarg; break;
```

and parse everything later..

am i completely going the wrong way?
if so, please guide me how to properly use getopt....

thanks:)

Comment: Yes, you're going in the right direction. You need to keep the already parsed/processed options internally and check conflicting options down the track

Answer (score 0):

You can use the condition checking inside the switch case options like the below example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int select=0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int opt;
        while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ab")) != EOF)
        {
                switch(opt)
                {
                        case 'a' :
                                if(select == 0)
                                {
                                        printf("The a option is given\n");
                                        select=1;
                                }
                                break;

                        case 'b' :

                                if(select == 0)
                                {
                                        printf("The b option is given\n");
                                        select=1;
                                }
                                break;
                }
        }
}
```

Output:-

$ ./a.out -a

The a option is given

$ ./a.out -b

The b option is given

$ ./a.out -b -a

The b option is given

$ ./a.out -a -b

The a option is given

In this example the a or b option in the same command line argument, only once it come.

If any option is entered the select variable becomes one, otherwise it is zero, if one option is entered it set the select to 1. So, it skip the next options using the if condition.

It takes the first argument only after that it skip all the arguments.
If you want to produce error, you can use the else part in the if conditions.

Comment: i dont want something trivial like this.